# How to disable that double-clicking on a shape converts it to a path in Adobe XD?

Tags: adobe-xd

In Adobe XD, when you create a shape and then double-click on it in the Layers sidebar, you convert it to a path. Once converted to a path it cannot be reverted back to a shape, since Adobe XD doesn't know the shape of this path.

When I'm trying to select a layer that's in many nested folders I accidentally convert shapes to paths and don't notice that. Then when I go back to editing the shape (that was already converted to path) I can't just <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> at that point.

How can I disable this feature?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. The only thing you can do is be careful :/

Comment: Drink less coffee? 

Comment: It cannot be disabled presently. I created a post requesting to have an option to disable the conversion to path when you are double clicking. If you are interested in it, please like the post. **https://community.adobe.com/t5/adobe-xd/disable-double-click-for-conversion-to-path/m-p/11253184?page=1**